# CMD command in C# gives no Output

Tags: c#, cmd

For context, I'm trying to write a program which gathers a specific WLan key. For that I start a CMD process, before executing the command and reading all lines, while saving them to a txt file.
Thr problem is, that the text file contains the command and everything, but not the output of the command:

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.613]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\Heinz Mtze\Desktop\CMD-Test>netsh wlan show profiles name="DaWlan" key=clear | findstr Schlüsselinhalt

C:\Users\Heinz Mtze\Desktop\CMD-Test>

When I try, copying the exact code displayed above in a CMD instance, everyhing workes just fine. So, does anyone know, what the problem might be?

My Code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var p = new Process();
            var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            p.StartInfo = startinfo;
            p.Start();

            using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine($"netsh wlan show profiles name=\"{network_in}\" key=clear | findstr Schlüsselinhalt");
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
            using (StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput)
            {
                if (sr.BaseStream.CanRead)
                {
                    string output;
                    output = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    File.WriteAllText($@"{path}Data\out.txt", output);
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            string schlüssel = File.ReadLines($@"{path}Data\out.txt").Skip(4).Take(1).First();
            label4.Text = schlüssel;
            //File.WriteAllText($@"{path}Data\out.txt", String.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: Each time I see someone launch another process through cmd.exe rather than directly (i.e. Launch netsh.exe rather than cmd.exe), I die a little inside.

Comment: Does it matter tho?

Comment: Why are you redirecting standard input?

Comment: I am redirecting standart input to write to the cmd console using streamwriter

Comment: It matters because you're trying to automate cmd.exe to launch a command and it's an approach that is causing you issues. Just launching netsh.exe itself would probably give you far fewer issues. So would using cmd.exe /c "netsh blah blah blah" to be honest, but that's a bad way to do it, so just launch netsh.exe direct from C#.

Comment: First of, I'm using findstr because I dont know hoe I can filter this line from C#. Also I'll rewrite the Programm for english systems, when everything works fine.

Comment: You may also consider to _not_ do all this on the Event Thread in order to keep your application and its UI responsive.

Comment: I am not that experienced with coding. I dont know what you're talking about :/